# SvelteKit: Implementing endpoint by file (not directory)

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm learning SvelteKit and lately I've seen in a tutorial (attached bellow) that should be possible to make a route using only a file (not a directory). In the tutorial they create api.ts file that containts http request methods. The route is then accessed by "/api" path and a json data is displayed in a browser. But when I do the same I get 404 erro code.

This is my routes/api.ts file:

```
export function GET(request) {
  return { body: "HELLO!" };
}
```

I then access this url: localhost: http://localhost:5173/api, but get 404 error code.

**My question is:** Is this solution still possible in the latest sveltekit version? If yes, then how?

I'm using sveltekit 1.15.8.

Tutorial link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FSCUj7DgfUE&list=PLoKaNN3BjQX0Ch8C6XHjG4K1Q75ugf6yG&index=7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible. Every route now needs a directory.

Comment: I don't like this :-/ The project would look much cleaner without having bunch of directories that contains only one +server.ts file.

Comment: I have not used SvelteKit to build complex APIs, just mainly pages. For an API I probably would be tempted to implement that separately e.g. using NestJS, which comes with additional features like dependency injection.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a hook https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks
And route your paths to some exported functions.
But it's not sveltekitest way of doing.

You can check slug concept https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing
Which is a powerful mecanism.

If you use graphql, you'll have only one route /graphql and your graphql engine will handle resolving.